# div overlap over another within same body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website : [my site](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)

in the nav bar ,when you click on the "teamchart" ,it will take you to that portion.

Now the problem here is that ,it is overlapping with the contact section.How do I align the chart and then the contact portion to come after that.

Why is this happening ?

kindly help or advice me.God bless.

code involved with the website :

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];
var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];
var dataWeeks = ["Week 1: 32<br>Week 2: 54<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 12", "Week 5: 22<br>Week 6: 14<br>Week 7: 12<br>Week 8: 03<br>Week 9:44", "Week 10: 14<br>Week 11: 11<br>Week 12: 23<br>Week 13:20 <br>Quarter 1 :25", "Week 14: 53<br>Week 15: 16<br>Week 16: 11 <br>Week 17:33", "Week 18: 52<br>Week 19: 22<br>Week 20: 12 <br>Week 21 :09 <br>Week 22:34", "Week 23: 59<br>Week 24: 87 <br>Week 25:36<br>Week 26:78<br>Quarter 2 :56<br>Half Yearly 1 :98", "Week 27: 69<br>Week 28: 33<br>Week 29: 11<br>Week 30: 65", "Week 31: 69<br>Week 32: 33<br>Week 33: 99<br>Week 34: 66<br>Week 35: 19", "Week 36: 84<br>Week 37: 16<br>Week 38: 66<br>Week 39: 11<br>Quarter 3 : 77", "Week 40: 86<br>Week 41: 21<br>Week 42: 52<br>Week 43: 12<br>Week 44: 37", "Week 45: 90<br>Week 46: 69<br>Week 47: 19<br>Week 48: 17", "Week 49:33 <br>Week 50:09 <br>Week 51:44 <br>Week 52 : 89<br>Quarter 4 :66<br>Half Yearly 2:99"];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return months[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);

  text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.html(dataWeeks[i])
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px')
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  });


  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

```css
.fl-lt {
  float: left;
}
.fl-rt {
  float: right;
}
/* Clear Floated Elements
---------------------------------*/

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.figure {
  margin: 0px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0px !important
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* Primary Styles
---------------------------------*/

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #888888;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #888888;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Navigation
---------------------------------*/

.main-nav-outer {
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px #ececec;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.main-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 17px 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7cc576;
}
.small-logo {
  padding: 0 32px;
}
.main-section {
  padding: 90px 0 110px;
}
/* Clients
---------------------------------*/

.client-part {
  background: url(../img/section-bg1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 55px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.client-part-haead {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 41px;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
  font-family: ''Open Sans',sans-serif';
  font-style: italic;
}
.client {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.client li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.client li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.client li a img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.client li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.client li a h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.client li a span {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.quote-right {
  font-style: normal;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #7cc576;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 68px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #7cc576;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.quote-right:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.c-logo-part {
  background: #7cc576;
  padding: 25px 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.c-logo-part ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.c-logo-part ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 25px;
}
.c-logo-part ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.main-section.team {
  padding: 85px 0;
}
.main-section.team h6 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
/* Talk Business
---------------------------------*/

.business-talking {
  background: url(../img/section-bg2.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 60px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.business-talking h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Contact
---------------------------------*/

.main-section.contact {
  padding: 90px 0 100px;
}
.main-section.contact {
  background: url(../img/bg-map.png) left 190px no-repeat;
}
.contact-info-box {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 14px 68px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.contact-info-box h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  float: left;
  width: 102px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.contact-info-box h3 i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.contact-info-box span {
  line-height: 28px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.social-link {
  padding: 35px 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 68px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
.social-link li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.social-link li a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #222222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.social-link li a:hover,
.social-link li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.twitter a:hover {
  background: #55acee;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  background: #3b5998;
}
.pinterest a:hover {
  background: #cb2026;
}
.gplus a:hover {
  background: #dd4b39;
}
.dribbble a:hover {
  background: #ea4c89;
}
.form {
  margin: 0 66px 0 30px;
}
.input-text {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.input-text:focus {
  border: 1px solid #7cc576;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(124, 197, 118, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(124, 197, 118, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(124, 197, 118, 0.3);
}
.input-text.text-area {
  height: 165px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
.input-btn {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #7cc576;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.input-btn:hover {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}
.validation {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#sendmessage {
  color: #7cc576;
  border: 1px solid #7cc576;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#errormessage {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#sendmessage.show,
#errormessage.show,
.show {
  display: block;
}
/* Animation Timers
---------------------------------*/

.delay-02s {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.delay-03s {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.delay-04s {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.delay-05s {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.delay-06s {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.delay-07s {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.delay-08s {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.delay-09s {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.delay-1s {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.delay-12s {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  position: absolute;
}
path {
  stroke: #0d0d0d;
  /* stroke-width: 5px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: fill 250ms;
  transition: fill 250ms;
}
path:hover {
  /* stroke-width: 10px; */
  fill: #fff;
}
text {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5px;
}
.main-section.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 820px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Homepage</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/x-icon">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800italic,700italic,600italic,400italic,300italic,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">.pie {behavior:url(PIE.htc);}</style><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/classie.js"></script>

<script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
    <!--main-nav-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#header">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#service">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="small-logo">
          <a href="#header">
            <img src="img/small-logo.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#client">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">TeamChart</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--main-nav-end-->

  <section class="main-section client-part" id="client">
    <!--main-section client-part-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <b class="quote-right wow fadeInDown delay-03"><i class="fa-quote-right"></i></b>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p class="client-part-haead wow fadeInDown delay-05">It was a pleasure to work with the guys at Knight Studio. They made sure we were well fed and drunk all the time!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="client wow fadeIn delay-05s">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/client-pic1.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>James Bond</h3>
            <span>License To Drink Inc.</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--main-section client-part-end-->
  <div class="c-logo-part">
    <!--c-logo-part-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/c-liogo1.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/c-liogo2.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/c-liogo3.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/c-liogo4.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/c-liogo5.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--c-logo-part-end-->


  <!-- chart section -->

  <section class="main-section team" id="team">
    <!--main-section team-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <h2>TeamChart</h2>
      <h6>Chart talks about the points required</h6>
      <div class="chart-wrapper"></div>
      <button onclick='replay()'>Replay</button>
      <div class="textt" data-tip="this is the data ."></div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!--main-section team-end-->





  <section class="business-talking">
    <!--business-talking-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Let’s Talk Business.</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--business-talking-end-->
  <div class="container">
    <section class="main-section contact" id="contact">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-7 wow fadeInLeft">
          <div class="contact-info-box address clearfix">
            <h3><i class=" icon-map-marker"></i>Address:</h3>
            <span>308 Negra Arroyo Lane<br>Albuquerque, New Mexico, 87111.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info-box phone clearfix">
            <h3><i class="fa-phone"></i>Phone:</h3>
            <span>1-800-BOO-YAHH</span>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info-box email clearfix">
            <h3><i class="fa-pencil"></i>email:</h3>
            <span>hello@knightstudios.com</span>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info-box hours clearfix">
            <h3><i class="fa-clock-o"></i>Hours:</h3>
            <span><strong>Monday - Thursday:</strong> 10am - 6pm<br><strong>Friday:</strong> People work on Fridays now?<br><strong>Saturday - Sunday:</strong> Best not to ask.</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="social-link">
            <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="pinterest"><a href="#"><i class="fa-pinterest"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="gplus"><a href="#"><i class="fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa-dribbble"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 wow fadeInUp delay-05s">
          <div class="form">

            <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
            <div id="errormessage"></div>
            <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control input-text text-area" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="input-btn">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('#test').scrollToFixed();
      $('.res-nav_click').click(function() {
        $('.main-nav').slideToggle();
        return false

      });

    });
  </script>

  <script>
    wow = new WOW({
      animateClass: 'animated',
      offset: 100
    });
    wow.init();
  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

      $('.main-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 102
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
   if you don't want to use the easing effects:
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
   }, 1000);
   */
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    })
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {


      var $container = $('.portfolioContainer'),
        $body = $('body'),
        colW = 375,
        columns = null;


      $container.isotope({
        // disable window resizing
        resizable: true,
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: colW
        }
      });

      $(window).smartresize(function() {
        // check if columns has changed
        var currentColumns = Math.floor(($body.width() - 30) / colW);
        if (currentColumns !== columns) {
          // set new column count
          columns = currentColumns;
          // apply width to container manually, then trigger relayout
          $container.width(columns * colW)
            .isotope('reLayout');
        }

      }).smartresize(); // trigger resize to set container width
      $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function() {
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({

          filter: selector,
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/indexpiechart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple fix. In your CSS code under .chart-wrapper, you have position: absolute. Change position: absolute to position: relative and the overlap will disappear. In HTML/CSS elements should be displayed relative to one another to prevent overlapping. When you set an element's position to absolute, it will remain fixed in that position thus causing overlapping. Correct CSS:

```
.chart-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.I tried that.In that case the chart becomes invisible. @Jasg3

Comment: When I edited your code in Inspect Element, it worked perfectly and the chart remained visible. Are you sure you are only changing the position value from "absolute" to "relative" in .chart-wrapper{...} in css/stylepiechart.css Line 2? @jane

Comment: @jane it shouldn't. Test it out in your console.

Comment: yeah.Even I dont think it should happen. please see :http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/   @Jasg3

Comment: I cross checked after u guys said so.. @Damon

Comment: guys, I changed the website to the previous state,so that others can see the issue.Anyways,thanks for trying.God bless.